# Optiplex 980 wont wakeup

Tags: sleep, remote, desktop-computer

We have a desktop machine that appears to go into sleep mode (sleep is set to never in power options).  The user can remote into the desktop from her laptop successfully.  Yet, when we move the mouse or tap the keyboard...the machine will not respond.  She has to restart the machine from her remote session.

I tried a PS/2 keyboard thinking it may be a USB problem, no success.  Any ideas?

Specs: dell optiplex 980 with windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of computers are really bad at initializing sleep properly, sometimes this is a failure of the implementatino of the standard in the BIOS, sometimes this is a shortcoming of the OS not properly setting the system to sleep. In this scenario I would recommend not relying on sleep, as in most scenarios you can't improve the situation.

Comment: Sleep is disabled.

Comment: Check the event log for errors. If she can TS (remote desktop) to it, it's not asleep unless TS is waking it up. (and since sleep is disabled...) I'd look for display adapter errors. I had a display adapter that would die once in a while, without the OS itself crashing. Also, check to see if Windows has sleep/hibernate/other power saving thing enabled, separate from the BIOS.

Comment: @MarkAllen as an addition, Windows may be putting the graphical device into a lower power saving mode, this would be disabled in the device properties found in device manager (under the power tab)

Answer (score 0):

Update BIOS if available.  Check manufacturer's website.